# Flutter: Clip a Column or Row to prevent overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a layout structure in Flutter like this:

```
Inkwell
  Card
    ScopedModelDescendant
      Column
        Container[]
```

The number of containers in the column is variable.

The goal is that it should look like this:

[image: expected look]

But instead, it ends up doing this:

[image: actual look]

I've tried adding a `clipBehavior` property to the `Card`, and I've tried mixing in `ClipRects` anywhere in the structure, but nothing seems to work. My best guess is that a `ClipRect` above the `Column` doesn't help because the overflow happens *within* the column.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following message was thrown during layout:
flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 15 pixels on the bottom.
flutter:
flutter: The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
flutter: The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
flutter: black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
flutter: Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
flutter: RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
flutter: This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
flutter: seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
flutter: ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
flutter: like a ListView.
flutter: The specific RenderFlex in question is:
flutter:   RenderFlex#094c9 OVERFLOWING
flutter:   creator: Column ← ScopedModelDescendant<EventModel> ← Semantics ← DefaultTextStyle ←
flutter:   AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#5fe8b ink renderer] ←
flutter:   NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ← CustomPaint ← _ShapeBorderPaint ← PhysicalShape
flutter:   ← _MaterialInterior ← Material ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: <none> (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=56.0, h=104.3)
flutter:   size: Size(56.0, 104.3)
flutter:   direction: vertical
flutter:   mainAxisAlignment: start
flutter:   mainAxisSize: max
flutter:   crossAxisAlignment: stretch
flutter:   verticalDirection: down
flutter: ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget solves your problem. If there is not enough space to fit the child in a `Column` or `Row`, you can use `Wrap`. You can use `alignment`, `directionality` and `spacing` properties to customize it.

Here is the simple example:

```
class WrapExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      height: 180,
      child: Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Wrap(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
          runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
          children: <Widget>[
            Chip(
              avatar: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('AH')),
              label: Text('Hamilton'),
            ),
            Chip(
              avatar: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('ML')),
              label: Text('Lafayette'),
            ),
            Chip(
              avatar: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('HM')),
              label: Text('Mulligan'),
            ),
            Chip(
              avatar: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('JL')),
              label: Text('Laurens'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This worked well! I didn't even need to specify the Wrap properties, because the elements inside it already have padding/margin. Just `Wrap(children: ...)`. I'll wait a day before marking this as accepted, but this solved my problem -- thanks!

Comment: You need to set `clipBehavior` property in `Card` widget as well

Answer (score 1):

You can also just wrap the widget you want to allow overflowing in a `Positioned` inside a `Stack` widget and set the the `Positioned` parameter `top: 0`.

Works like charm for me

Answer (score -2):

This problem occurs because the column widget determine it's size as big as it's can based on the received constraints from it's parents. However, the total size of the children are shrink-wrap based on what they need. And the later is bigger.

To solve this problem. Following ways can be helpful:

- Make the column calculate flex based on children sizes instead of it's default behavior (which is be as big as it can based on constraints passed from parents). To do this, wrap your children in `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget.
- Use widgets that default is to shrink-wrap it's size, which is `Wrap`, as the current solution suggests.
- Use `SingleChildScrollView` which clips the space, ignoring the required size of children.

I don't know why sometimes `Column` can take constraint with too less space for their children as I don't look deeper into the problem. But according to flutter layout principles this could happen. Hope someone can give insights to this :).